# *** glibc detected *** /filepath/ : double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000007bed40 ***

Tags: linux, c, glibc

I need to understand the below C error,

```
*** glibc detected *** /path/readnbn: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000007bed40 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x76508)[0x7f12d024e508]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7f12d025354c]
/path/readnbn[0x405e2c]
/path/readnbn[0x406712]
/path/readnbn[0x40758e]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x7f12d01f6c16]
/path/readnbn[0x401629]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0041a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 537221975                          /path/readnbn
00619000-0061a000 r--p 00019000 fd:00 537221975                          /path/readnbn
0061a000-0061b000 rw-p 0001a000 fd:00 537221975                          /path/readnbn
0061b000-007d3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f12cbdea000-7f12cbdff000 r-xp 00000000 68:05 792                        /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7f12cbdff000-7f12cbffe000 ---p 00015000 68:05 792                        /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7f12cbffe000-7f12cbfff000 r--p 00014000 68:05 792                        /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7f12cbfff000-7f12cc000000 rw-p 00015000 68:05 792                        /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7f12cc000000-7f12cc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f12cc021000-7f12d0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f12d01d8000-7f12d0347000 r-xp 00000000 68:05 544                        /lib64/libc-2.11.3.so
7f12d0347000-7f12d0546000 ---p 0016f000 68:05 544                        /lib64/libc-2.11.3.so
7f12d0546000-7f12d054a000 r--p 0016e000 68:05 544                        /lib64/libc-2.11.3.so
7f12d054a000-7f12d054b000 rw-p 00172000 68:05 544                        /lib64/libc-2.11.3.so
7f12d054b000-7f12d0550000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f12d0550000-7f12d056f000 r-xp 00000000 68:05 537                        /lib64/ld-2.11.3.so
7f12d075b000-7f12d075e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f12d076c000-7f12d076e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f12d076e000-7f12d076f000 r--p 0001e000 68:05 537                        /lib64/ld-2.11.3.so
7f12d076f000-7f12d0770000 rw-p 0001f000 68:05 537                        /lib64/ld-2.11.3.so
7f12d0770000-7f12d0771000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff4e78c000-7fff4e7ad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff4e7e0000-7fff4e7e1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [backtrace](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html): apparently the `readnbn` program either freed a block of memory that had been freed before (with either `free()` or some other method), or the heap got corrupted somehow. However, with no debugging symbols available there are no function names, so I can't tell you anything else. You'll have to trace the fault: hopefully you have debug symbols (or can recompile.) If you have a core dump, you could [analyze it with `gdb`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb).